# Exact match in dget function with an array as the criteria

Tags: google-sheets

[Example Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BBYvEendr-RFzs4RzmLd_C7D5LoYg6hHiH-p90VixN0/edit#gid=981404299) I'm trying to get an exact match with an array in the criteria section of dget. Maybe there is another way to work around this, but I'm trying to give it a dynamic component in the array.

=dget('Micro Data'!$A$1:J,"PCR Score",{"Micro Type","Stage Type","Tank","ID#";"PCR PAL","Bright",F2,H2})

Sometimes all criteria matches multiple data points except the "Tank". However the tanks won't exactly match. Ex. All the data is the same in two data sets, except the tanks are CT1 and CT18. This then comes up with the #NUM! error. I'm trying to find if there is a way to get an exact match in the array data while still allowing it to reference the cell?

I know there is the option of making it "=XXX" making it a txt string, but this would take away the dynamic function. I would also loose the auto updating aspect when more data is added.

Thanks

Comment: Ryan, it would be helpful if you could share a small sample sheet, editable by all, that demonstrates your issue.  Also show what the desired result should look like, given the data you have.

Comment: Yes, please at least share a sample of data and the desired outcome.

Comment: I linked in a sample sheet. I cut a little bit out but the overall process should function the same and the issue is still the same.

Comment: Ryan, we can't access your sheet - please share it as "editable by all" to allow us to help.  That's why we always recommend sample sheets with sample data.  See here: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/138382/how-to-share-a-google-sheets-demo-spreadsheet/138383#138383

Comment: O I'm sorry I thought I changed that. There we go.

Comment: Ryan, just doing some testing on a copy of your sheet.  I don't know DGET well enough to understand why it matches CT1 with CT18.  I'll do some more reading.  But I'm pretty sure I can get you the same result with a query, which I'm more familiar with.  Give me a few minutes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ryan, see my solution using a query, in Retain Log-GK, cell F2.  I think it is just as dynamic as the dget, but perhaps not.  It will need some error wrapping to avoid errors if no result found.

Formula is basically:

```
=query('Criteria Source'!A2:J5,
  "select J where B = '"&D9&"' and C = '"&D10&"' and E = '"&D11&"' and D ='"& D2 & "' ",0)
```

I made all of the criteria dynamic, though obviously you can do it whatever way suits you best...

Let me know of any questions.  I'll check back later...

Comment: Thank you for that, but I don't think that quite capture what I need. And maybe I've done a poor job laying out my full problem and only gave a tiny snapshot of it. The "retain log" is continuing to have data entered to it daily. While the "criteria" tab is a query coming from, which I've realized I can remove the tab and just query it into the data section of dget. So it is an ever evolving data tab And I'm almost positive there would be a way to add an exact match function to the array. I just can't figure it out...yet. Or maybe I'm not fully wrapping my head around what you managed to do.

Comment: I'm sorry I spoke too soon... I got it to work. Thank you!

Comment: Glad it helped!  Post again if you have any other issues.